# Default Controller Mapping?

Tags: input

It seems like different controllers have their buttons mapped differently. I was wondering if there was some sort of standard. X is the first button, then A, then B, then Y. I looked and couldn't find any standards anywhere.

EDIT: I'm specifically talking about controllers used with computers. Usually with 2 joysticks, a hat, 4 letter buttons, 2 triggers, and 2 bumpers.

Comment: It's not guaranteed for a game controller to have an X button. For instance most NES USB controllers only have A and B. They'll probably won't have a pre-defined standard for this same reason. They don't want to leave out 2 numbers in this sequence because the xbox controller has an A and B instead of square and triangle

Comment: Balint but most controllers for computers have 4 buttons(ABXY or whatever)

Comment: NES controllers are used with computers. A lot of people use emulators

Comment: Balint I'm talking about the standards for the more common controllers. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no completely universal standard.

Anyone could make a USB gamepad that looks outwardly like a standard Xbox controller, for example, but reports its buttons to the PC in a completely arbitrary order that doesn't match up to any other device. Even the same controller can report its controls in a different order depending on the host platform & driver.

[The Rewired project includes an attempt to fit a wide array of common PC gamepads to a shared template](http://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/docs/ControllerMaps.html#controller-templates). While they cover [many devices](http://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/docs/SupportedControllers.html), it's still not a universal standard, but it's the most comprehensive standardization attempt that I know of.

[image]